# set terms to category and subcategory

Tags: categories, terms

I am developing a import plug in where I would upload a text file which contain all sorts of data about vehicle and that would insert that data in custom post type vehicle.

Now I am having problem inserting a category and its subcategory.

Like I have term audi and a term a3 I would like to add audi as category and a3 as its subcategory and assign to that post.

I tried

```
wp_set_object_terms( $news_arr[0], array(utf8_encode($news_arr[2]),$news_arr[3]), 'vehicle_models', $append = false ) ;
```

where `$news_arr[2]` and `$news_arr[3]` are audi and a3 respectively.

I also tried `wp_insert_terms` and set it parent as id of the first set object terms that creates a subcategory but does not assign to that post.

any help will be appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out 
first set the terms to post through wp_set_object_terms  and then run a update query in term_taxonomy table and set parent id of the the second term to first term.

```
$taxo = wp_set_object_terms( $news_arr[0], utf8_encode($news_arr[2]), 'vehicle_models', $append = false ) ;
$child = wp_set_object_terms( $news_arr[0], utf8_encode($news_arr[3]), 'vehicle_models', $append = true ) ;
$category_parent    = get_term_by('name', $news_arr[2], 'vehicle_models');
                    $category_child     = get_term_by('name', $news_arr[3], 'vehicle_models');
                    $category_parent_id = $category_parent->term_id;
                    $category_child_id  = $category_child->term_id;
                    $wpdb->update( 
                    $wpdb->prefix.'term_taxonomy', 
                    array( 
                        'parent' => $category_parent_id,
```

`), 
                array( 'term_id' => $category_child_id ) 

            );`